# MS EXCEL. Преобразование строки с полным ФИО в Фамилия И.О

Tags: excel, vba

Необходимо в таблице MS Excel преобразовать колонку с полным ФИО вида `Фамилия Имя Отчество` к виду `Фамилия И.О.`. Вручную – не вариант, так как записей в колонке несколько тысяч.

Есть ли какие-то инструменты в Excel для такого действия, например, преобразовать по заданному шаблону данные исходного столбца в новые данные и поместить их в новый столбец?

Похоже, формулы exel, связанные с текстом громоздки для решения, и напрашивается применение VBA скрипта, но синтаксис я его не знаю совсем... Хотя, алгоритм прост - разбирается строка полного ФИО на список слов, затем формируется новая строка из преобразованных элементов этого списка и сохраняется в новой ячейке. По идее, нужно добавить возможность указания в качестве параметров начальную ячейку исходного и результирующего столбца.

Comment: *Есть ли какие-то инструменты в Exel для такого действия* Отож... называется "Формулы". Но это получить из исходного значения в другой ячейке. Если изменить значение в той же ячейке - то только процедурой в VBA-модуле.

Comment: Один примерчик, бы, неплохо показать для понимания, как текстом в формулах манипулировать..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)+1)&"."&ЛЕВБ(СЖПРОБЕЛЫ(ПСТР(ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;" ";ПОВТОР(" ";50));99;150)))&"."

=ЛЕВБ(A2;ПОИСК(" ";A2)+1)&"."&ПСТР(A2;ПОИСК("/";ПОДСТАВИТЬ(A2;" ";"/";2))+1;1)&"."
```

`UDF` с возможностью выбора параметров. `Application.Trim` - перед обработкой текст очищается от лишних пробелов

```
Function fFIO_(sTxt As String, Optional sSeparator As String = " ", Optional sSymbol As String = ".")
    Dim sTmp As String
    
    sTxt = Application.Trim$(sTxt)
    sTmp = Left$(sTxt, InStr(sTxt, sSeparator) + 1) & sSymbol
    fFIO_ = sTmp & Left$(Split(sTxt, sSeparator)(2), 1) & sSymbol
End Function
```

В ячейку:

```
=fFIO_(A2;" ";".")
```

Answer (score 2):

Довольно непростая формула, суть в том, что надо разбивать строку по символам. Например брать пробел, затем брать нужную часть (левую, середину, правую) и всё это затем конкатенировать с помощью `&" "&`, в имени и отчестве надо брать только первый символ с помощью `LEFT`.

В данном примере предполагается что в ячейке A2 лежит имя вида "Иванов Иван Иванович"

```
=LEFT(A2; SEARCH(" ";A2;1)-1)&" "&LEFT(MID(A2;SEARCH(" ";A2) + 1; SEARCH(" "; A2;SEARCH(" ";A2) + 1) - SEARCH(" ";A2) -1);1)&". "&LEFT(RIGHT(A2; LEN(A2) - SEARCH(" "; A2;SEARCH(" ";A2;1)+1));1)&"."
```

Comment: *брать нужную часть (левую, середину...)* - вычислить положение первого пробела и добавить 1

Answer (score 1):

Как раз вручную - самый правильный вариант, так как записей в колонке несколько тысяч.

[image: Мгновенное заполнение ячеек]

Этот инструмент называется "Мгновенное запронение" ([Flash Fill](https://support.microsoft.com/ru-ru/office/%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%bc%d0%b3%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-excel-3f9bcf1e-db93-4890-94a0-1578341f73f7?ui=ru-ru&rs=ru-ru&ad=ru))

Comment: Вы забыли уточнить, что этот инструмент стал доступен только в последних версиях  (возможно, в `Excel-2013` его еще не было)

Comment: @vikttur Слова Flash Fill - это ссылка на статью в support.microsoft.com. Сразу после заголовка написано *Excel для Microsoft 365 Excel 2019 Excel 2016 Excel 2019 для Mac Excel 2013 Excel 2016 для Mac* Так что был он и там... Больше примеров [здесь](https://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/7/7751/)

Comment: Сомневался, потому и написал "возможно". В 2010 и более старых нет мгновенного заполнения